# Calculating the relative homology of a space with an $n$-cell attached.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $Y$ arise from $X$ by attaching an $n$-cell. I am asked to calculate $H_n(Y, X;A)$. As $X$ is a closed inclusion in $Y$ and $X$ is a deformation retract of $Y \backslash \{0\}$ where $0$ is the $0$ of the $n$-cell, we have that $H_n(Y, X;A) \cong H_n(Y/X, X/X;A) \cong H_n(Y/X, pt;A) \cong H_n(Y/X;A)$.

By taking a few examples I think it should be $H_n(Y/X;A) \cong H_n(X;A) \oplus A$, but do not know how to prove it.

Comment: hint: $Y/X \cong D^n/S^{n-1} \cong S^n$

Comment: Also, strictly speaking $H_n(Y/X, pt;A) \cong \tilde{H}_n(Y/X;A)$, but for singular/cellular homology the reduced and unreduced versions happen to coincide for $n>0$.

Comment: @William I don't understand why $Y/X \cong D^n / S^{n - 1}$. For example, can't we take $X = S^3$ and $Y = S^3 \wedge S^1$ (so we attach a $1$-cell on its edge to a given point in $X$), in which case $Y/X \cong S^3$ which is not homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Comment: In your example $Y/X$ *is* homeomorphic to $S^1$ because you're collapsing the $S^3$ part, in general $(A \vee B)/A \cong B$ (the symbol $\wedge$ is used for the "smash" product, $\vee$ is the wedge product, written slash-"vee"). If $Y$ is made by attaching a $D^n$ to $X$ by gluing along a map $f\colon S^{n-1} \to X$, i.e. we could write $Y = X \cup D^n$, then in $Y$ when we collapse the subspace $X$ it also collapses the attaching sphere so that what's left is homeomorphic to $D^n/S^{n-1}$.

Comment: @William ah right, had $X$ and $Y$ mixed up. Thanks again.